# AJAX pass to PHP Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am passing serialized data and a variable as well to php, but i am getting an unexpected token '(' error in the data section

if i take out the 'lid':userID from the data section, it works fine.

```
$("#cname").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: {$("#cname").serialize(), 'lid':userID},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            $.mobile.changePage($('#page-tasklist'));
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: do you need `crossDomain: true`?

Comment: yes, its to a separate server

Comment: You might want to try to use a newer version of jQuery or a non-jquery solution and see if it works. I have seen code that has glitched due to jQuery before (it was an outdated version he was using). This is probably not he problem, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the `.serialize()` method is a string like `action=login&UserName=&Password=&Site=Test`. So try this instead.

```
$("#cname").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#cname").serialize() + '&lid=' + userID,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            $.mobile.changePage($('#page-tasklist'));
        },
    });
});
```

Also, if you just remove `lid: userID` from your ajax request, you would actually *still* get an error because `{$("#cname").serialize()}` is not valid json. The `data` parameter can accept either an encoded string like what `.serialize()` returns or a json object.

The following 2 examples are equivalent:

```
$.ajax({url:'index.php',type:'POST',data:{z:1,y:2}});
$.ajax({url:'index.php',type:'POST',data:'x=1&y=2'});
```

Comment: What isn't sending properly? I tested this and it seems to work. What is being sent and what are you expecting?

Comment: my information isn't going to my php file properly, i know this because its not being stored in my db

Answer (score 0):

Try add to variable and then push new key/val.

```
$("#cname").submit(function (e) {
    var serializeData = $("#cname").serializeArray();
    serializeData.push({'lid':userID})
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: serializeData,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            $.mobile.changePage($('#page-tasklist'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I fixed his post to work. The contents of the push needed to be modified. It should be `{name: 'lid', value:userID}`